# Подключить несколько элементов навигации в slick slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Использую slick-slider. Нужно подключить для навигации - точки и кнопки с названием товара. Как сделать что бы все работало одновременно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.searched__slider').slick({
      arrows: true,
      dots: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 1000,
      swipe: false,
      touchMove: false,
      appendDots: '.searched__box-dots',
      dotsClass: 'searched__dots',
      appendArrows: '.searched__arrow',
      prevArrow: $('.searched-arrow--prev'),
      nextArrow: $('.searched-arrow--next'),
   })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сверстать вторую навигацию отдельно и привязать её к слайдеру при помощи событий и методов `slick-slider`:

```js
$('.slider-block__main').slick({
  prevArrow: '<span class="slider-block__arrow slider-block__arrow--prev">〈</span>',
  nextArrow: '<span class="slider-block__arrow slider-block__arrow--next">〉</span>',
  dots: true,
  dotsClass: 'slider-block__dots',
  customPaging: function(){return ''}
})

//при прокрутке слайдера обозначаем новый активный элемент навигации
$('.slider-block__main').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  $(this).siblings('.slider-block__nav').children().removeClass('active').eq(nextSlide).addClass('active');
});

//при клике на элемент навигации прокручиваем слайдер в нужную позицию
$('.slider-block__nav li').click(function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  $(this).closest('.slider-block').find('.slider-block__main').slick('slickGoTo',index);
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.slider-block__nav{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slider-block__nav>li{
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.slider-block__nav>.active{
  border-color: black;
  background-color: #cda;
}
.slider-block__arrow{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: calc(50% - .75em);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider-block__arrow--prev{
  left: 0;
}
.slider-block__arrow--next{
  right: 0;
}
.slider-block__slide{
  padding: 100px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #acd;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.slider-block__dots{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slider-block__dots>li{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 5px;
}
.slider-block__dots>.slick-active{
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider-block">
  <ul class="slider-block__nav">
    <li class="active">Slide 1</li>
    <li>Slide 2</li>
    <li>Slide 3</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="slider-block__main">
    <div class="slider-block__slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="slider-block__slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="slider-block__slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Всегда  интересовал меня вопрос , можно ли инициализировать слик без джэйкуери ? Как вы думаете ?

Comment: Я как-то видел `slick-slider` под React, но думаю, что это чьё-то народное творчество, к которому Ken Wheeler не причастен

Comment: А так в коде оригинального плагина сплошь и рядом используются методы `jQuery`. Понятно, что при желании можно переписать на нативный JS, но зачем? Для этих целей есть `Swiper`. Fancybox вон от `jQuery` ушёл

Comment: Да согласен, спасибо